# Froala - 100% Height causes bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I'm loading my website in an iFrame which is using Froala, everything is working as intended until the window has to resize. What happens is that the buttons which opens *popups* in Froala no longer opens, until I click them a second time.

Here's a video to show what I mean:
https://puu.sh/u8D2D/510a746b2b.webm

Here's the code which resizes the iframe:

```
function resize() {
    var window_height = $(this).height();
    $("iframe").height(window_height);
}

$(window).resize(resize);
resize();
```

If I remove the last line which makes the first resize once the iFrame is loaded, everything works. It's only when the height of the iframe is set that Froala starts acting weird.